# SSIS- why the extension cannot be update on my visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

i don't understand why i can install my extension SSIS

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx3kX.jpg)**your text**

when i try to execute a package Child fron a controller package i got this erreur

Error: Error 0x80040154. Failed to create an instance of empty child package. The Distributed Component Object Model (DCOM) configuration or the installation of SQL Server Integration Services, may be corrupted on your machine.

i try to execute a package Child from a  controller package ssis